# loopback bug acl not working?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

i m try to implement acl for model(named as company)

```
      "relations": {
       "user": {
       "type": "belongsTo",
       "model": "user",
       "foreignKey": "company_id"
     }
   },
      "acls": [
           {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "DENY"
        },
     {
         "accessType": "*",
         "principalType": "ROLE",
         "principalId": "$owner",
          "permission": "ALLOW"
      }
   ],
```

deny all user and access only to authenticated user owner of that object . here i m also try to add permission for super user who have  all permission in short admin and owner of objec(data) can do crud is there any soultion for this please help

Answer (score 0):

You can deny all unauthenticated users then deny everyone and allow only the owner like below :

```
{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
},

{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
},   

{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
}
```

you need only CRUD for the $owner, you can assign the properties needed for your user as below :

```
    {
              "accessType": "*",
              "principalType": "ROLE",
              "principalId": "$owner",
              "permission": "ALLOW",
              "property": [
                 "find",
                 "create",
                 "updateAll",
                 "delete"
          ]
    }
```

For the super user you should create this Role and assign it to one of your users.

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "superuser",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
}
```

How to create a ROLE ? you can follow the documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html).

And make sure that you have this file `/server/boot/autentication.js`and authetication is enabled : `server.enableAuth()`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {
  // enable authentication
  server.enableAuth();
};
```

For more ACL tricks please read the official documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html).

Comment: @Rocky can you make it clear, what is not working do you have errors ? please reproduce the steps you made thank you

Comment: it throw unauthorized if i remove deny all i.e 2 acl rule then it show all data i.e owner who has not belong to that data

Comment: which ACLs exactly did you remove ?

Comment: {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
},

Comment: did you add these properties to the $owner ?  `"property": [
                 "find",
                 "create",
                 "updateAll",
                 "delete"
          ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166629/discussion-between-anouar-kacem-and-rocky).

Comment: thanks for you help if get anything i will let you know